# Python: How to flatten list of lists where each sublist is a contains a single float

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, flatten

I want to flatten my list that looks as follows:

```
generated = [[108.88114502], [19.29647502], [4.08611068], [52.33578872], [134.54672018], [14.22388561], [22.04375228]]
```

To something like this:

```
flat_list = [108.88114502, 19.29647502, 4.08611068, 52.33578872, 134.54672018, 14.22388561, 22.04375228]
```

I tried the following but I get a TypeError saying floats are unsubscriptable:

```
flat_list =  [item for sublist in generated for item in sublist]
```

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python list comprehensions; compressing a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077015/python-list-comprehensions-compressing-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: No it is a list, sorry I forgot the commas. However if I try @TrentonMcKinney 's way I get the typeError

Comment: I edited my code now @JohnColeman

Comment: If `generated` is exactly as edited then `[item for sublist in generated for item in sublist]` works fine, as you should be able to verify. Please read about the importance of providing a [mcve]. You have not provided enough information for others to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### After OP edits and comments

- *TypeError saying floats are unsubscriptable* when using `[item for sublist in generated for item in sublist]` means the list elements are single values and single values in a list (e.g. `[[14.22388561], [22.04375228], 34.6576]`)
- Check if each element is a list.

  - If `item` type is a list, take the value at index 0, assuming each list contains only 1 value.
  - If `item` type is not a list, take `item`

```py
generated = [item[0] if type(item) == list else item for item in generated]
```

### Solution from before OP edited the question

- I'm guessing `generated` is a `np.array`, so you can use [`.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy-reshape)

  - If a `np.array` is printed, the output looks like that shown by the op, a list with no `,`
  - The array shown, has the shape `(7, 1)`, and you want it reshaped to `(1, 7)`

```py
g = generated.reshape(1, 7)

# display g
array([[108.88114502,  19.29647502,   4.08611068,  52.33578872,
        134.54672018,  14.22388561,  22.04375228]])
```

- If `generated` is a list, converting it to a `np.array` and using reshape will work.

```py
generated = np.array(generated)

generated = generated.reshape(1, 7)  # where 7 is the length of the list)
```

### `%%timeit` comparison

#### Given `g` as a list of lists

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(365)
g = [[np.random.randint(100000)/100] for _ in range(1000000)]
```

Test

```py
%%timeit
[item for sublist in g for item in sublist]
74.6 ms ± 415 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
np.array(g).reshape(1, 1000000)
243 ms ± 2.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### Given `g` as a (1000000, 1) np.array

```py
np.random.seed(365)
g = [[np.random.randint(100000)/100] for _ in range(1000000)]
g = np.array(g)
```

Test

```py
%%timeit
[item for sublist in g for item in sublist]
867 ms ± 3.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
g.reshape(1, 1000000)
289 ns ± 1.16 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flat = [l[0] for l in generated]
```